# Command Execution Exception: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named student I want to assign a fee or update (if present), I am looping over them which worked fine until I deleted a student. So now whenever I run the stored procedure it shows error.

Here is my code.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_AutoAssignFeeUpdate]
(
    @FeeID int,
    @FeeAmount int,
    @Fine int,
    @DueDate date,
    @AppliedON date,
    @FeeMonth varchar(30)
)
AS 

--- Variables Using in Loops
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT , @MaxStudentID INT, @StdID INT, @FID INT

-- Setting Counter From the count of students in student table if they are 'Active'

SELECT @LoopCounter = min(AdmissionNumber) , @MaxStudentID = max(AdmissionNumber) 
FROM StudentTable

-- WHILE Loop Condition 
WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxStudentID )
BEGIN
    --- SELECT IDs all Active students and matching with counter
   SELECT @StdID = AdmissionNumber 
   FROM StudentTable WHERE AdmissionNumber = @LoopCounter AND Active = 'True'

      --- CHECK IF ROW EXITS
   SELECT @StdID = AdmissionNumber
   FROM FeeAssociationTable
   IF EXISTS ( SELECT FeeMonth FROM FeeAssociationTable 
                    WHERE @LoopCounter = AdmissionNumber AND FeeID = @FeeID AND FeeMonth = @FeeMonth)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE FeeAssociationTable
            SET FeeAmount = @FeeAmount, Fine = @Fine , DueDate = @DueDate
            WHERE @LoopCounter = AdmissionNumber AND FeeID = @FeeID
            AND  FeeMonth = @FeeMonth
        END

    ELSEBEGIN
        INSERT FeeAssociationTable 
        (FeeID, AdmissionNumber, FeeAmount, FeeMonth, DueDate, Fine, AppliedOn, [Status])

        VALUES 
        (@FeeID, @LoopCounter, @FeeAmount, @FeeMonth, @DueDate, @Fine, @AppliedON, 'Pending')
    END
   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END
```

This is working if the Ids are continuous. What should I do if there is an Id missing or how to skip that specific number which is not present in the studentTable.

**Explanation:**

The loop take the initial value of `min(id)` from `studentTable` set as counter, and final value of `max(id)`.

The loop compares both values `id` in `studentTable` and counter of the loop.

Then for each counter student in the table the the fee is assigned.

```
INSERT FeeAssociationTable 
        (FeeID, AdmissionNumber, FeeAmount, FeeMonth, DueDate, Fine, AppliedOn, [Status])

        VALUES 
        (@FeeID, @LoopCounter, @FeeAmount, @FeeMonth, @DueDate, @Fine,
```

The problem is here, while inserting I am using @LoopCounter. Lets say `@LoopCounter = 100` but `StudentTable` is skipping ***100*** and there is 101 there. The conflict rises. Because the SQL can't find the `**100**` id in the studentTable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic being implemented.  Non-working code does not necessarily do a very good job of explaining a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use an `sp_` prefix for naming your stored procs. That prefix is reserved for Microsoft's *system* procedures (and incurs a minor performance hit to boot)

Comment: Also, do not use "sp_" at the beginning of your stored procedure names - Microsoft has reserved that, and it can cause problems.  Include your table structures when you post the sample data.  Finally, please provide the exact, full error message.

Comment: Iterating over a set of Ids will work better if you use a cursor.  I suggest looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @GordonLinoff as I said my code is working.

Comment: @Koen, we won't have to increment as we do in Loop?

Comment: All of these `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s seem to be entirely independent. From what I can see, this whole thing should be replaced by a single `MERGE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, this whole thing looks like it can be replaced by a `MERGE`. Don't do things *one step at a time* when you can tell the server what to do *with the entire set* of rows.

Something like:

```
MERGE INTO FeeAssociationTable t
USING (SELECT AdmissionNumber, @FeeID as FeeID, @FeeMonth as FeeMonth FROM StudentTable
       WHERE Active = 'True') s
ON t.AdmissionNumber = s.AdmissionNumber AND
t.FeeID = s.FeeID AND
t.FeeMonth = s.FeeMonth
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET FeeAmount = @FeeAmount, Fine = @Fine , DueDate = @DueDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(FeeID, AdmissionNumber, FeeAmount, FeeMonth, DueDate, Fine, AppliedOn, [Status])
VALUES
(@FeeID, s.AdmissionNumber, @FeeAmount, @FeeMonth, @DueDate, @Fine, @AppliedON, 'Pending');
```

Not sure I've got all of the conditions quite right, but you should be able to see what I'm driving at, I hope.

---

Your actual issue could have been "solved" by replacing:

```
SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1
```

with:

```
SELECT @LoopCounter = MIN(AdmissionNumber) FROM StudentTable
   WHERE Active = 'True' and AdmissionNumber > @LoopCounter
```

but don't do that, please.

Answer (score 1):

Man , you should use a For each . For example:

```
DECLARE yourCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC
FOR SELECT AdmissionNumber
FROM StudentTable

OPEN yourCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM yourCursor INTO @StdID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

/*
 CHECK IF EXIST FOR UPDATE OR INSERT
*/

FETCH NEXT FROM yourCursor INTO @StdID
END
CLOSE yourCursor
DEALLOCATE yourCursor
GO
```

This replace your while.

Comment: Um, this doesn't contain a "For each". And it still contains a `WHILE`. All you've done is switch one way of looping for another when in most cases, we should strive to *avoid* writing loops if a set-based approach is viable.

Comment: how would I know which at `AdmissionNumber` are. I need the `AdmissionNumber` so I can insert it in another table